# how to raise inner repeater itemcommand event

Tags: asp.net, repeater

Here is what my current logic looks like

```
<asp:repeater>

    <asp:button id="btnMain"/>

  <asp:repeater>
     <asp:button id="btnChild"/>
  </asp:repeater>

</asp:repeater>
```

On click of "btnchild", I need to open up user control in overlay to do some of kind of verification and once user provide the information, I need to further process the "btnChild" command.

The logic is kind of pausing the itemcommand event and require some user verification and move forward with the itemcommand on user verification.

So how can i raise repeater's itemcommand event on submitting overlay data?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't pause the item command event; essentially, the click of the dialog that displays the user confirmation must then trigger the rest of the action.  This means you have to store enough information about the object in the command (such as storing keys in viewstate or session related to the objects being evaluated), and re-query any data or get the values from session/viewstate and continue on with the process.

HTH.

Comment: Yes I am doing the same but I was looking for any better solution if available.

Comment: There's nothing streamlined; events can't be paused through postbacks, and a confirmation requires that the current process ends and that the page has rendered to the client.  So the process has to be disconnected.